# DOM Element in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have three panels and want to know which panel is on foucs how do I know that?

I want to ask which element is right on foucs and then i want to add a Class.

```
myApp.directive('myDir', function ($rootScope, $interval) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
    }
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $interval(function () {
            var data = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();

            for (var i = 0; i < $rootScope.gazePoints.length; i++) {
                var x = $rootScope.gazePoints[i].x;
                var y = $rootScope.gazePoints[i].y;
                if (x >= data.left && x <= data.right && y >= data.top && y < data.bottom) {  

                    var look = element.children('panel1');
                    if (look == element) // is not working
                    {
                        console.log("found")
                        element.addClass('onFocus');
                    }             
                }
            }

          }, 3000);
        }
     };
  });
```

Also not working:  document.getElementById('panel1');

my html:

```
<div class="container" my-dir></div>
        <div class="panel panel-primary" id='panel1'>
               <div class="panel-body">
                        Panel content1
               </div>
         </div>
         <div class="panel panel-primary" id='panel2'>
               <div class="panel-body">
                        Panel content2
               </div>
         </div>
         <div class="panel panel-primary" id='panel3'>
               <div class="panel-body">
                        Panel content3
               </div>
         </div>
 </div>
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Focus and Blur are input field events. You can add class when user click one of tabs. Is that what you trying to achieve?

Comment: No i don´t really want to "focus"  i just want to know which element is the current element. Because i have three panels. And i don´t know how can I know which element in link is the current one

Comment: Do you use getBoundingClientRect() to get this "focus" effect work on mobile/tablets ?

Comment: no. only on the normal desktop. I am using an eyetracker and want to analyse  where the user is looking

Answer (score 0):

I think the inner function was a bit irritating. Now you can see that i just want to know which element is the current one.

```
myApp.directive('myDir', function ($rootScope, $interval) {
return {
restrict: 'A',
scope: {
}
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    $interval(function () {

       var look = element; // the current but how do I know which panel???


      }, 3000);
    }
 };
```

});